# Braided vector space: motivation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, motivation, braid-groups

In one of my courses we were given the definition of a braided vector space:

> Let $k$ be a field. A braided vector space is a pair $(V,s)$ with
>
> - $V$ a $k$-vector space
> - $s:V \otimes V \rightarrow V \otimes V$ an invertible linear map which obeys the equation $(s \otimes id_V) \circ (id_V \otimes s) \circ (s \otimes id_V)= (id_V \otimes s) \circ (s \otimes id_V) \circ (id_V \otimes s)$.

- Why are these vector spaces any interesting? How should one think about them?

To me the definition comes out of the blue.
My thoughts so far: The condition for $s$ appears to be something like the Reidemeister move type III. So, braided vector spaces seem like building blocks for linear representations of the braid group. Namely, given a braided vector space $(V,s)$ there is a group homomorphism $p_n: B_n \rightarrow Aut(V^{\otimes n}); \sigma _i \mapsto s_i$ for any positive integer $n$. Here, $\sigma_i$ denotes the i-th generator of the braid group, while $s_i$ refers to the automorphism on $V^{\otimes n}$ that „braids the i-th copy of the tensor product.“ (I could make it more precise, but then reading it would be tedious. If it is unclear, please ask).

Comment: Have you heard about braided monoidal categories? In the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braided_vector_space) about braided vector spaces they are mentioned.

Comment: @Javi: I have heard about (non-braided) monoidal categories. As far as I can see, a braided monoidal category is a monoidal category with a special commutativity constraint. Are objects in the monoidal category of vector spaces over a field (with regular tensor product) with some braiding examples of braided vector spaces?

Comment: Follow up: Is any braided vector space an object in a braided monoidal category? And still - what are braided vector spaces/braided monoidal categories used for? What problems can they help solving? Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Yes, indeed, braided vector spaces are objects in a braided monoidal category. Each bradiding defines a braided monoidal category of vector spaces. As far as I know they are heavily used in QFT, mainly through different types of Hopf algebras and the Yetter-Drinfeld modules. There is also a correspondence that you can see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangular+Hopf+algebra), between a fixed kind of algebra or monoid and its category of modules. Braided monoidal categories appear as some of the module categories.

Comment: There is also the particular case of symmetric monoidal category, where the braiding is idempotent. These categories are of a lot of importance in modern algebra as they are the context to define [operads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/operad).

Comment: You could also find [this](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rosetta.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3IgGCKUdNkglBAFyaLHctA6V_1Bf0IVABIJ9A_aDnjlCVM1u_sgvm_YUc) interesting

Comment: @Javi: Thanks a lot!